# iPhone application build fails first time, succeeds second time even after "Clean All Targets"

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm the build engineer for a new iPhone application and I've run into the following extremely weird situation. We're using git with Xcode 3.2.4 under Snow Leopard.

This happens whether I'm using the Xcode GUI or using xcodebuild on the command line.

- I clone a clean copy of the repository and run "Build" or "Build and Archive".
- The build fails with a bunch of compile errors.
- I run "Clean All Targets" with "Also clean dependencies" and "Also remove precompiled headers" checked
- I run "Build" or "Build and Archive" again.
- Build succeeds.

The errors all seem to be of the form "file-something.h no such file or directory", but the files it claims it can't find are actually there.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? The git repo uses submodules, and as far as I can tell, all the "missing" files are contained in one of the submodules. However, as I noted, the files *are* present in the working directory, and the submodules have been inited and updated correctly.

Comment: Since you say the files are present, it seems likely the problem is related to the build process, not git. (But I'm not sure enough to remove the tag!)

Comment: Yeah, me neither, which is why I put it there. If someone comes up with a git-acquitting answer, I'll remove it. :-)

Comment: What's remaining in your build directory after you to a Clean All?

Comment: To supplement Ryan's comment: you could use git to help see what's being left behind after the failed build and clean. `git status` to see untracked files, `git diff` if anything got modified, and `git ls-files -i` to see ignored files. It seems like this would have to turn up some difference - maybe a generated build config file which causes new build flags the second time, so that it finds the header files correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if I manually create all the build directories and their subdirectories before running a build (after a fresh clone), the build succeeds. Because of the submodules, there are actually three build/ directories (one in the main project, one in each submodule) and the submodule ones have a bunch of subdirectories.

This *has* to be due to a bug somewhere, and I will continue to research it, but at least for the moment I have a workaround and can get on with creating my automated build.

Edit: And in fact, this appears to be due to a bug in the build of one of the two submodules, [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20). I'm guessing that it creates the build directories *after* it tries to use one or more of them. I will take this up with the three20 developers.